# Regex.split, how to read left of the matched pattern

Tags: c#, regex, perl

I am trying to convert a Perl script to a C# 3.5 routine.

The perl code I have is:

```
if($work =~ /\<[0-9][0-9][0-9]\>/){
    $left       = $`;
    $match      = $&;
    $work       = $';
}
```

In C# I wrote the following code:

```
string[] sSplit = Regex.Split(work, @"\<[0-9][0-9][0-9]\>");
if sSplit.length is > 2
{
    left = sSplit[0];
    match = sSplit[1];
    work = sSPlit[2];
}
```

However the above is not giving me the matched pattern in `sSplit[1]`, but the content to the right of the matched string instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Regex.Split` is not what you need. The equivalent to `=~ /.../` is `Regex.Match`.

However, `Regex.Match` has no equivalent to Perl’s `` $` `` or `$'`, so you need to use a workaround, but I think it’s a fair one:

```
var m = Regex.Match(work, @"^(.*?)(\<[0-9][0-9][0-9]\>)(.*)$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (m.Success)
{
    left = m.Groups[0].Value;
    match = m.Groups[1].Value;  // perhaps with Convert.ToInt32()?
    work = m.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the match index and length to get the stuff:

```
var m = Regex.Match(work, @"^\<[0-9][0-9][0-9]\>");
if (m.Success)
{
    left = work.Substring(0, m.Index);
    match = m.Value;  // perhaps with Convert.ToInt32()?
    work = work.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
}
```

Comment: Would you not want either (.*?) on the end too or (.*) on both? I'm just wondering what happens if the matching string repeats itself and you want to get all matches and what's to their left and right... Though that is a bit beyond the scope of this question as I read it.

Comment: @Chris: Whether the second one is `(.*?)` or `(.*)` makes no difference because of the `$` after it. The first one is important: it is `(.*?)` so that you get the first match. With `(.*)` you would get the last.

Answer (score 2):

When trying regular expressions, I always recomment [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), which is an online tool that visualizes your .NET regular expressions. In this case, use Regex.Match and use Groups. That'll give what you want.

Note that the backslash in `\<` and `\>` are not needed in C# (nor in Perl, btw).

Also note that `` $` ``, `$&` and `$'` have equivalents in C# when used in a replacement expression. If that's what you need in the end, you can use these "magic variables", but only in Regex.Replace.

Answer (score 1):

A `split` is usually asking to *throw* away the delimiters. Perl acts just the same way (without the verboten `$&` type variables.)

You capture delimters in Perl by putting parens around them:

```
my @parts = split /(<[0-9][0-9][0-9]>)/; # includes the delimiter
my @parts = split /<[0-9][0-9][0-9]>/;   # doesn't include the delimiter
```